# How do you set the color of a pixel under the cursor on a FMX.Canvas?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

With vcl I used this:

```
procedure MovingDots(X, Y: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas); stdcall;
begin
{$R-}
  Inc(ALooper);
  ACounter := ACounter shl 1; // Shift the bit left one
  if ACounter = 0 then
    ACounter := 1; // If it shifts off left, reset it
  if (ACounter and 224) > 0 then // Are any of the left 3 bits set?
    // FMX.Canvas does not have Pixels
    ACanvas.Pixels[X, Y] := ASelectionColor1 // Erase the pixel
  else
    ACanvas.Pixels[X, Y] := ASelectionColor2; // Draw the pixel
{$R+}
end;
```

How can I set the color at X,Y from a FMX Canvas?

Comment: The thanks are appreciated, but you should put those into a comment with the question you want to say thank you for, not in the body of a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [`example`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/FMXTBitmapDataPixel_%28Delphi%29), this should work:

```
var
  vBitMapData : TBitmapData;
  ASelectionColor : TAlphaColor;
...
// Define ASelectionColor somewhere
// Get write access to the bitmap
if ACanvas.Bitmap.Map (TMapAccess.maWrite, vBitMapData) then
begin
  try
    vBitmapData.SetPixel (x, y, ASelectionColor); // set the pixel color at x, y
  finally
    ACanvas.Bitmap.Unmap(vBitMapData);
  end;
end;
```

Note that the mapping strategy with locking/unlocking the bitmap was introduced in FM2, i.e. Delphi-XE3.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, isn't this correct [`FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.Bitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.Bitmap)?

Comment: Oh dear, I appear to be blind. I was on the verge of writing the exact same answer yesterday when I concluded that `TCanvas` did not have a `Bitmap` property. Oh well. At least your eyes work! +1

Comment: Note than in Delphi 10.4 this code doesn't work because of some issue with TMapAccess.Write. Replacing with TMapAccess.ReadWrite works.